# Passing punctuaton marks through command line in C

Tags: c, bash, ubuntu, io, program-entry-point

I have a program that reads a natural language sentence from command line and does something with it.

Some punctuation marks are not accepted: either I get a specific error message (like when I use parenthesis), or I get `>`(for example when I type `'`), as if the terminal is still waiting for something.

A quick fix is to include the single "problematic" words in quotation marks, but it doesn't seem like a great fix to me.

Isn't there a way to prepare the command line to take any character as a valid input, without having the 'user' to think about what to include in quotation marks or not?

For the sake of completeness, that's how I coded the command line thing: `int main(int argc , char ** argv){`, I guess it's the standard way.

I'm using the last Ubuntu, don't know if that's relevant.

Comment: A shell command *must be in valid shell syntax*. There's not really any way around this; if you want to use English on the command line, you need to represent it in a shell-compatible form (i.e. use appropriate quotes, escapes, etc). If you want your program to accept plain English text, you can have it read input from the terminal after starting, rather than taking it as argument(s).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is less to do with your program and more to do with what is invoking it.

When invoking your program from a shell (like `bash`), the shell will try to do you a favor and split the command line arguments on whitespace.  It'll also interpret special characters like `>`, `;` and `(` for redirection, splitting commands, and starting subshells.

In order to turn this behavior off, these special characters must be escaped by preceding them with a `\` or by enclosing command line arguments in single- or (only in most cases) double-quotes.

This is only a requirement if your program is executed by a shell.  If it's executed by a program you control, you will have direct control over the list of arguments passed to your program (the `argv` in your program's `main()` function).

Comment: I'd actually have said "single- or (in some cases) double-quotes."  Single-quoting is stronger quoting in most shells.  In bash and other Bourne-family shells, for instance, the only thing single-quoting doesn't quote is single quotes, whereas certain characters are still special inside double quotes.  But +1, regardless.

Comment: Yeah; this was my original wording and is actually my preference (single quotes first, then double quotes if necessary).  Since this wording implies that single quotes are less effective, I'll revert.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is not with C.  This is how the command line works.  there are characters with special meaning.  Quotation marks allow you to override that.  That is the 'fix'.

Answer (score 0):

you can skip the input by `\`.
So, the script does not interpret the caracter. Instead of that, it will consider it litteraly.